# MS SQL 2017 to MySql 8 migration with MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

I've got a problem during migration. To migrate data between SQL Server 2017 and MySQL I use MySQL workbench (version 8.0.12). When script for new tables generation is completed I can find that there are many places where int is set to default value of '', for example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myname`.`Table1` (
  `version` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
...
)
```

And this, of course, is not working in next steps. Since I've got 'version' column in each table, is there any way that I can change this globally?

I know that I can go to each table and change it manually but it will be a lot of clicking...

Comment: Unfortunatelly there is no workaround. However it seems you found an issue. Please fill a bug report at https://bugs.mysql.com. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, bug reported :) Bug #92417

Comment: Thanks @PastorPL